# Android - URI not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs )

Tags: java, android

I created an android application and published it, I want to update it but it keeps giving this error. 
URI not registered (Settings | Language & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)

I have checked everywhere but none of those solved my problem. 
Please see screen shots below
[image]

[image]